# Convert InnoDB to MyISAM with InnoDB disabled

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I'm the lucker owner of a webhotel where the host changes settings without telling.
When thats said,
I have some tables in my database that are running with InnoDB engine.
But over the night the host have disabled InnoDB, so I cant convert it to MyISAM with ALTER command.

Anyway I can get the data out of the database, or convert it to MyISAM when InnoDB is disabled?

Only thing I see all the time is,

> `#1033` - Incorrect information in file: 'file.frm'

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the InnoDB engine has been disabled? If the mysql server was upgraded, for instance, there could be a problem with the InnoDB log files, and the engine would appear as disabled... You should contact the owner.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you need to have `InnoDB` enabled so that `MySQL` could read the data for conversion.

To recover the data on another instance, you would need `ibdata*` files from `MySQL` root data directory as well as all `*.ibd` files from your database directory (if your `MySQL` setup had `innodb_file_per_table` enabled).

Comment: Can't get into root since I aint hosting it myself.

Comment: So that means I am kind of stocking with my data lost?

Comment: @user: unless you did your own backups (and you did them, right?), there is nothing can be done unless your providers shows some mercy and reenables `InnoDB` to let you do the backups.

Comment: I'll bet on they show mercy then.. I though my cPanel was doing automatic backups everyday, but it turned out it didn't..

Comment: Even though that aint any excuse for me, not to do it myself, which I of course should have done.