# MySQL features I can rely on being available

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

So I'm developing a PHP/MySQL based CMS which requires PHP 5.1 and MySQL 5.0 (with InnoDB support) at least. I'm now wondering what features of MySQL I can safely use without noticing one day that "Oh, well, that crappy hoster has disabled feature X, damn, now I'm screwed."

So my question is, which of these features can become problematic (= can be disabled, require special configuration, require user privilege):

- transactions and FKs in InnoDB (of course unavailable to MyISAM)
- table locking (MyISAM and InnoDB)
- stored procedures

I just want to know once and for all what's the minimal feature set I can expect from MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored procedures require a privilege to create them.

Transactions and locks are always available, `FK` are too as long as you have permissions on both tables involved.

There was a [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692895/convert-innodb-to-myisam-with-innodb-disabled) asked about half an hour ago in which a user asked "what to do when the host disabled `InnoDB` engine".

Answer (score 0):

Everything that you mentioned is built-in as part of the particular engine and therefore can be customized (to some extent) on a per engine basis. However, most of the time, the default settings is the way to go.

In other words, programming your CMS in a way that is compatible with all possible configuration scenarios is impractical (and in my opinion, a waste of time). Stick with the default and make it part of the requirements.

---

Some aspects of the behavior of transactions in the InnoDB engine can be customized but not disabled.

Stored procedures are only available MySQL version 5.0 onwards.

---

Of all in the list, I would say stored procedures are the less "stable" ones, and things might change slightly in future releases. Probably by adding new features.